# Access Store on different screens in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-redux, store, react-native-navigation

I am using a 'react-native-navigation' module for navigation in my app. I have declared my screens as below

```
import Screen1 from '../container/Screen1';
import Screen2 from '../container/Screen2';

const store = myStore();

Navigation.registerComponent('Screen1',() => Screen1,store,Provider);
Navigation.registerComponent('Screen2',() => Screen2,store,Provider);

Navigation.startSingleScreenApp({

screen:{
    screen:'Screen1',
    title:'Screen1',
    navigatorStyle:{
        navBarHidden:true
    }
}
});
```

My challenge is to use store on different screens so that i can dispatch an action. Is there any way i can achieve that?

Note: myStore is declared in another file fulfilling all reducer, thunk configuration.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, even though you pass `store` and `Provider` in registering each screen, you still just `connect` the components you want subscribed to the store and use Redux in the normal way. So:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Screen1)
```

I'm assuming because you tagged your question with [react-redux](/questions/tagged/react-redux) that you understand the use of that library. If not, check out [Usage with React](https://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use it using connect method below is sample demo

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Screen1)
```

For some screen let say Screen2 if you not want to change value of store and only want to use store value then you can pass null as mapStateToProps

```
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Screen2)
```

For some screen let say Screen3 if you want to change value(performing action) of store only but not want to display value then you can avoid passing mapDispatchToProps

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Screen3)
```

sample code you can find here
https://github.com/rajscet/react_redux_basic